# Arduino nano が勝手にモーターに電圧を入力する

Tags: arduino

Arduino nanoには「uという変数に格納されているだけの電圧を、pwmで送れ」というプログラムを書き込んでいます。そして、Jupiter notebookのpythonで書いたプログラムで、シリアル通信によってAruduino nanoのuという変数を書き換えます。
これによって、Jupiter notebookからモーターの制御が可能です。

問題なのはここからです。uを書き換えて、モーターに目的の動作をさせて、制限時間をすぎると、プログラムは終了します。モーターもウィインと静かな音を立てて止まりかけます。

すると、次の瞬間、モーターの電源電圧の最大までモーターに印加されて、モーターが猛スピードで正転します。止まることはないです。止める方法はArduino nanoの電源を奪うかArduino nanoのリセットボタンを押すかです。

Jupiter notebookの停止ボタンを押しても意味がありません。そもそもプログラム自体は実行されていないという判定になっているからです。

この現象は、１０回実行すると７回くらいの割合で起きます。どなたか原因を策に心当たりありませんでしょうか

プログラミングの問題ではないので（なぜならプログラムが終了した後におこる問題だから）、ソースコードは割愛します。もし、ソースコードに可能性がある場合はおっしゃってください。

Comment: プログラミングの問題ではないと考えているならこのサイトは相応しくないのでは？ [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) こちらのサイトの方が同様の話題が多くありそうですが。[モーターを動かすとRCサーボが暴走します。原因が不明です。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13183815913), [モーターのノイズかもしれない質問です。](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12106243452) 他にはこんな資料も。[Arduino ビギナーのためのモーター,リレー,ブザー制御入門](https://www.elekit.co.jp/product/docs/addpage_file160.pdf)

Comment: 「Jupiter notebookの停止ボタンを押しても意味がありません。そもそもプログラム自体は実行されていないという判定になっているからです」というのは、どういう意味ですか？
「制限時間をすぎると、プログラムは終了します」の"プログラム"は、Jupiter notebookのプログラムですか、Arduinoのプログラムですか？
まず、どういうシステム構成なのかを説明すべきです。
「モーターもウィインと静かな音を立てて止まりかけます。すると、次の瞬間、モーターの電源電圧の最大までモーターに印加されて、モーターが猛スピードで正転します」で書かれているモーターへの印加電圧はどのようにして確認したのでしょうか？
ソースコードに全く問題が無いのに、プログラムした意図と異なる動作をするのだとすれば、『ソースコードに全く問題が無い』という想定が間違っている可能性が大です。
Arduino nanoの動作が異常になるのは、Arduino nanoに印加されている電源にノイズがのっている等の可能性もあります。

Comment: プログラムを終了させてしまうのが問題の可能性があります。終了後はプログラムが動いていないので、出力が決定されておらず、そのため状況によって状態が変わっていると考えられます（この辺は、回路の組み方によりますが）。今回の場合では、最後は無限ループで停止状態を維持するのが一番簡単な解決手段だと思われます。

Comment: みなさんありがとうございます。プログラムでない領域で問題があると思ったので、色々試しましたところ、電源を変えるとノイズがなくなりました。